# My site breaks at 760px. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

```js
window.onload = function(){

  const pattern = trianglify({
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
          cellSize: 75,
          xColors: 'Blues',
          yColors: 'match',
          variance: 0.75,
          fill: true,
        })
        document.getElementById('background').appendChild(pattern.toCanvas())
        
      /* Customization
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        cellSize: 75,
        variance: 0.75,
        seed: null,
        xColors: 'random',
        yColors: 'match',
        fill: true,
        palette: trianglify.colorbrewer,
        colorSpace: 'lab',
        colorFunction: trianglify.colorFunctions.interpolateLinear(0.5),
        strokeWidth: 0,
        points: null
      }
      */

let ageInput = document.querySelector('#ageInput');
let heightInput = document.querySelector('#heightInput');
let weightInput = document.querySelector('#weightInput');

let extremeWeightGain  = document.getElementById('extremeWeightGain')
let averageWeightGain  = document.getElementById('averageWeightGain')
let mildWeightGain  = document.getElementById('mildWeightGain')
let mildWeightLoss  = document.getElementById('mildWeightLoss')
let averageWeightLoss  = document.getElementById('averageWeightLoss')
let extremeWeightLoss  = document.getElementById('extremeWeightLoss')

let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let maintainCalories = document.getElementById('maintainCalories');

const selectElement = document.getElementById('exerciseInput')
let exerciseValue = {
  price: 0
}

selectElement.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const inputValue = e.target.value;
  
  if (inputValue == 'noExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = -150;
  }
  
  if (inputValue == 'lightExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = -50;
  }
  
  if (inputValue == 'moderateExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = 100;
  }
  
  if (inputValue == 'activeExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = 250;
  }
  
  if (inputValue == 'veryActiveExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = 375;
  }
  
  if (inputValue == 'extraActiveExercise') {
    exerciseValue.price = 500;
  }
  
})

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  let zyzz = parseFloat(weightInput.value*10) + parseFloat(heightInput.value*6.25) - 
parseFloat(ageInput.value*5) + parseInt(genderValue.price) + parseInt(exerciseValue.price);

  maintainCalories.innerText = zyzz.toFixed(0);    

  extremeWeightGain.innerText  = zyzz  *100  /71;
  averageWeightGain.innerText  = zyzz  *100  /81;
  mildWeightGain.innerText  = zyzz  *100  /89;
  mildWeightLoss.innerText  = zyzz  *88 /100;
  averageWeightLoss.innerText  = zyzz *76 /100;
  extremeWeightLoss.innerText  = zyzz *66 /100;

  extremeWeightGain.innerHTML = Math.round(extremeWeightGain.innerHTML *1);
  averageWeightGain.innerHTML = Math.round(averageWeightGain.innerHTML *1);
  mildWeightGain.innerHTML = Math.round(mildWeightGain.innerHTML *1);
  mildWeightLoss.innerHTML = Math.round(mildWeightLoss.innerHTML *1);
  averageWeightLoss.innerHTML = Math.round(averageWeightLoss.innerHTML *1);
  extremeWeightLoss.innerHTML = Math.round(extremeWeightLoss.innerHTML *1);
});

  var genderValue  = {
    price: 0
  }
  var maleValue  = document.getElementById('Male');
  Male.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
    genderValue.price  =  5;
  })
  var femaleValue  = document.getElementById('Female');
  Female.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
    genderValue.price  =  -161;
  })

}

        function showResults() {
        document.getElementById("input1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("input2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("input3").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("input4").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("input5").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("input6").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('hideButton').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("resultsSection").style.display="block";
        }
```

```css
.main-section {
    padding-top: 79px;
    padding-left: 500px;
    width: 903px;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    display: block;}
.background {
    position: sticky;
    overflow: hidden;}
.wholeArea {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;}
.title {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #132c54;}
.description {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2569c8;
    line-height: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;}
.inputText {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #132c54;
    background-color: white;}
.inputField {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #132c54;
    border-color: #132c54;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    outline-color: #132c54;
    border-radius: 6px;}
.noDecoration { /* No Text Decoration */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #132c54;}
.selectInput {
    width: 413px;
    color: #132c54;
    outline-color: #132c54;
    outline-width: 0px;
    border-color: #132c54;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;}
.textInput {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
    color: #132c54;
    outline-color: #132c54;
    outline-width: 0px;
    border-color: #132c54;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 3px;}
.selectOption {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #132c54;}
.buttonStyle {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #132c54;
    background-color: white;
    outline-color: #132c54;
    outline-width: 0px;
    border-color: #132c54;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;}
.radioStyle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;}
.leftColumnBox {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}
.leftColumnBox2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 321px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}
.rightColumnBox {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}
.rightColumnBox2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 321px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}
.leftColumn {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 81px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;}
.rightColumn {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 81px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;}
.advertImage {
    border: 10px white solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;}
.resultsSection {
    display: none;}
.radioArea {
    height: 45px;
    width: 700px;
    display: block;}
.inputArea {
    height: 50px;
    width: 700px;
    display: block;}
.labelText {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;}
.resultsText {
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;}
.hideInput {
    display: block;}
.mainBorder {
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;}
.titleBorder {
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;}
.descBorder {
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;}

a:link { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .main-section {
        padding-top: 64px;
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 0px;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .leftColumn {
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 41px;
        margin-left: 85px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        float: left;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .rightColumn {
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 41px;
        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .advertImage {
        border: 10px white solid;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
    }
    .leftColumnBox2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .rightColumnBox2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .textInput {
        width: 350px;
    }
    .selectInput {
        width: 363px;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .description {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .labelText {
        width: 150px;
    }}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .main-section {
        padding-top: 64px;
        padding-left: 11%;
        padding-right: 0px;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .leftColumn {
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 41px;
        margin-left: 88px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        float: left;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .rightColumn {
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 41px;
        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .advertImage {
        border: 10px white solid;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
    }
    .leftColumnBox2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .rightColumnBox2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .textInput {
        width: 350px;
    }
    .selectInput {
        width: 363px;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .description {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .labelText {
        width: 150px;
    }}

.banner { /* Banner Styles */
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;}
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
.noselect { /* No Highlighting */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
       -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                    supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */}
.banner-head-1 { /* Home Header */
    float: left; 
    overflow-wrap: normal; 
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display:block;}
.banner-head-2 { /* Food Header */
    float: left; 
    overflow-wrap: normal; 
    margin-left: 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display:block;}
.banner-head-3 { /* Exercise Header */
    float: left; 
    overflow-wrap: normal; 
    margin-left: 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display:block;}
.banner-head-4 { /* Calculators Header */
    float: left; 
    overflow-wrap: normal; 
    margin-left: 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display:block;}
.banner-head-5 { /* Calculators Header */
    float: left; 
    overflow-wrap: normal; 
    margin-left: 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display:block;}
.dropdown { /* Dropdown Content */
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;}
.noDecoration { /* No Text Decoration */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 20px;}
.banner-logo {
    height: 40px; 
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;}
.banner-logo-responsive {
    margin-left: 150px;
    height: 43px; 
    margin-top: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-left: 350px;}
.mobile-logo {
    height: 80px;
    padding: none;
    border: 10px white solid;
    border-radius: 8px;}


@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .banner-head-1 { /* Home Header */
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right:  10px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-2 { /* Food Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-3 { /* Exercise Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-4 { /* Calculators Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-5 { /* Calculators Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .banner-logo {
        height: 22px;
    }}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .banner-head-1 { /* Home Header */
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right:  10px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-2 { /* Food Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-3 { /* Exercise Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-4 { /* Calculators Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .banner-head-5 { /* Calculators Header */
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .banner-logo {
        height: 21px;
    }}
```

```html
<div class="mainBorder calculatorSection" id="inputSection">    <!-- Calculator -->
    <div class="radioArea" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" id="input1">
      <label class="inputText noDecoration labelText">Units</label>
      <a href="./calorie-calculator.html">
         <input type="radio" class="inputField radioStyle" onclick="window.location='./calorie-calculator.html'">
         <label class="inputText noDecoration">Metric</label>
      </a>
     <a href="./calorie-calculator-imperial.html">
          <input type="radio" class="inputField radioStyle" onclick="window.location='./calorie-calculator-imperial.html'">
          <label class="inputText noDecoration">Imperial</label><br>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="radioArea" id="input2">
      <label for="gender" class="inputText labelText">Gender</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Male" name="gender" value="5" class="inputField radioStyle">
      <label for="Male" class="inputText">Male</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Female" name="gender" value="-165" class="inputField radioStyle">
      <label for="Female" class="inputText">Female</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea" id="input3">
      <label for="ageInput" class="inputText labelText">Age</label>
      <input type="number" id="ageInput" class="inputField textInput" placeholder="12-80"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea" id="input4">
      <label for="heightInput" class="inputText labelText">Height</label>
      <input type="number" id="heightInput" class="inputField textInput" placeholder="100cm - 200cm"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea" id="input5">
     <label for="weightInput"class="inputText labelText">Weight</label>
     <input type="number" id="weightInput" class="inputField textInput" placeholder="30kg - 120kg"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea" id="input6">
      <label for="exerciseInput"class="inputText labelText">Exercise</label>
      <select id="exerciseInput" class="inputText selectInput">
        <option class="inputText selectOption">Exercise</option>
        <option value="noExercise" id="noExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Inactive</option>
        <option value="lightExercise" id="lightExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Light Activity</option>
        <option value="moderateExercise" id="moderateExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Moderate Activity</option>
        <option value="activeExercise" id="activeExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Active</option>
        <option value="veryActiveExercise" id="veryActiveExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Very Active</option>
        <option value="extraActiveExercise" id="extraActiveExercise" class="inputText selectOption">Extra Active</option>
     </select><br>
    </div>
    <button class="buttonStyle" onclick="showResults();" id="hideButton">ADD</button>
    <span class="resultsSection" id="resultsSection">
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Extreme Weight Gain(1kg/week) - <span id="extremeWeightGain" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Weight Gain(0.5kg/week) - <span id="averageWeightGain" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Mild Weight Gain(0.25kg/week) - <span id="mildWeightGain" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Maintain Calories - <span id="maintainCalories" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Mild Weight Loss(0.25kg/week) - <span id="mildWeightLoss" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Weight Loss(0.5kg/week) - <span id="averageWeightLoss" class="inputText"></span></div>
      <div class="inputText resultsText">Extreme Weight Loss(1kg/week) - <span id="extremeWeightLoss" class="inputText"></span></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Hi there,

I am trying to make my site responsive but it stops working at 760px. When it his 760px everything else gets moved and out of place. The problem happens when I click on a button to hide the input section and display the answers. Nothing is displaced on the button press for 760px+. The code is very similar at each code break and I can't find the issue.

Here is what it looks like before the button press:[img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP6bO.png)

Here is what it looks like after the button press[img-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG1Oq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have `radioArea` width set to 700px, maybe that's why? Width of your class are fixed, you have to change it according to screen width, if you want to make a responsive design
For example you can use width in percents, not in fixed pixels, but add `max-width` property, as you do not want to have it more than 700px

Comment: Thanks mate. You saved me a lot of time :)